# git-svn migration, error during pushing file to remote server

Tags: git, svn, controls, version, ref

I'm trying to migrate whole SVN repository to GIT repository. I've created dump file and loaded it using svnadmin load to local directory. After that, i've cloned repo and commit history using **git svn clone** command to specific folder (let it be /migration). After few days finally i got SVN repo on my computer localy. Last thing to do was to push whole svn repository to remote gitlab server. Firstly, i've added gitlab URL to /migration using

```
    git remote add origin git@gitlab.remote.server.com:project.git
```

This command was executed successfully. In the end, all i had to do was to push all files from /migration to git repository. So i typed:

```
    git push origin --all
```

And what i get as gitbash output:

```
    Enumerating objects: 231641, done.
    error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
    error: failed to push some refs to           'git@gitlab.remote.server.com:project.git'
```

I don't know, what might be a reason for theese errors, i've read, that it might be because of Protected Branches, that not so far where included in GitLab. But none of my attempts were good enough to fix theese problems.

This is all for Windows local pc. SVN version: 1.8.17 (r1770682), git version: svn, version 1.8.17

Comment: Same scenario and same issue here with
- git version 2.19.0.windows.1
- git-svn version 2.19.0.windows.1 (svn 1.9.7)
I have successfully migrated smaller svn repositories using the same commands, yet the biggest repo which, like yours, took several days to be cloned, fails. I guess it's a size issue ? Size does matter sometimes...